# Retrieve private messages data using Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api, endpoint

I am currently trying to build an app able to provide different data and analytics of a LinkedIn user. I would like to be able to retrieve all the user's messages and data such as whether it was viewed / answered.

Reading through the API's V2 doc I couldn't find anything apart from sending messages, which doesn't  help with what I'm trying to do. It seems like such functionalities were present on V1 but haven't been ported to V2.
Anyone got any idea if I can do that using LinkedIn API or any other means?